# Kendo UI DatePicker culture not working correctly with custom format

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-datepicker

I have this dojo with the code http://dojo.telerik.com/aginIY/2. 
The normal behavior should be that for the selected culture the format of the date is with "." (as in the first datepicker). But when entering a custom format, the culture does not matter anymore (datepicker 2 has "/").

For me this is a bug and I would like to have there the date with "." or with the separator of the currently selected culture. Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is maybe what you want http://dojo.telerik.com/aginIY/4

I think you may be confusing the formatting with parsing the acceptable input formats.

All I have done is changed your format statement to accept a number of different potential input formats

```
  $("#datepicker2").kendoDatePicker({
    culture: "de-DE",
  parseFormats: ["dd/ MMMM yy", "dd MMM yy", "dd/mmm/yyyy"]
});
```

See below link for the documentation

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#configuration-parseFormats

**UPDATE**

try this slightly different version. 
http://dojo.telerik.com/aginIY/6

This is just including more parsing options to get you to show the date as you want.

Comment: The format is received from an endpoint and is a userSetting within the database. And the final result that I want is not f.eg. 01.03.2017, but 01/ März 17, according to the format, but in de-DE culture

Comment: I have updated my answer with a slightly modified version. This has been expanded to include more "parsing" options.